# How do I recolour a photo using OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, colors

I have a grayscale photo that I am trying to colour programmatically so that it looks 'real', with user input 'painting' the colour (eg red). It feels like it should be simple, but I've been stuck trying a few ways that don't look right, so thought I'd ask the community in case I've missed something obvious. I've tried the following

- Converting to HSV, and combining the "Hue" and Saturation from the colour selected by the user, with the "Value" from the image. [image]
- Building a colour transformation matrix to multiply the BGR values (ie R = 0.8R + 1.1G + 1.0B). This works well for 'tinting', and adds a nice pastel effect, but doesn't really keep the depth or boldness of colour I want.
- (favourite so far - see answers) multiply RGB from colour channel by RGB of image.[image: Multiply - left colour channel, middle value, right combination]

Comment: Grayscale images simply don't have the color information, so it's impossible to extract. It will never look "real" without machine learning being able to find out what colors *should* exist in the image. See [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.07208.pdf) for an example of a CNN applied to this problem. Otherwise there are many different ways to colorize an image in a non-real way, but the question would need to be rephrased to have a target you want to achieve, and show exactly how your current methods have failed to hit that.

Comment: User will select which colour, my issue is making the greyscale image look like that colour, and keeping as much 'richness' in the features as possible (eg painting a transparent rectangle of colour over will wash it out, issues with saturation layer in my HSV approach). I'm looking to colorize in a plausible looking way with input from user.

Comment: Again, please include a target you want to achieve and how your methods have failed to hit that.

Comment: I saw [this](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/color_exposure/plot_tinting_grayscale_images.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-color-exposure-plot-tinting-grayscale-images-py) today and thought of your post.

Comment: Thanks for that -had another shot at HSV mixing (using HS from colour and V from grayscale image), it ends up looking too 'cartoony' for me, and doesn't deal well with grey colours. I can remedy the second issue by averaging between Value of colour and grey image, but still not right.  The multiply effect looks darker, but more real in my application. I might need to try a few different approaches (eg detect grey colours and handle them differently, and possibly correct for darkness created by multiply effects: scale by average brightness).

Comment: Theoretically, your RGB * grayscale intensity approach should be physically correct. It's related to the idea of "intrinsic images" - it's sort of the opposite problem. You want to apply a diffuse albedo to an object with known shading. You method works because "changes due to shading should affect R,G and B proportionally." (via: http://www-oldurls.inf.ethz.ch/personal/pomarc/courses/CompPhoto/cpv07.pdf). Also see: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/intrinsic/images/raccoon.html

Answer (score 0):

To add to the comment by user Alexander Reynolds, the question that you're asking is a known open research problem in the field of computer graphics, because the problem is under-constrained without using statistical priors of some sort. The state of the art in the CG community is found here, presented at SIGGRAPH 2016.

http://hi.cs.waseda.ac.jp/~iizuka/projects/colorization/en/

Also see: 
http://richzhang.github.io/colorization/

Comment: I've realised my question missed information: that the user / me is selecting a colour (eg a deep red), and my problem is making it look like the grey object in the image is red. Program is not required to pick which colours to use. I suspect this shouldn't need machine learning, though not sure what approach to take.

Comment: Seems like user should be selecting hue and saturation (H and S in HSV color space), and then the V (value) component can come from the grayscale image. Because grayscale is only giving you a clue as to the overall brightness of the scene.

Answer (score 0):

I've had another think and play with photoshop, and implemented a multiply blend mode on BGR space to get an ok result.
Implemented in java

> ```
> Mat multiplyBlend(Mat values, Mat colours) {//values 1 channel, colours 3
>     //simulates BGR Multiply blend mode 
>     ArrayList<Mat> splitColours = new ArrayList<Mat>();
>     Core.split(colours, splitColours);
>     Core.multiply(values, splitColours.get(0), splitColours.get(0), 1/255.0f);
>     Core.multiply(values, splitColours.get(1), splitColours.get(1), 1/255.0f);
>     Core.multiply(values, splitColours.get(2), splitColours.get(2), 1/255.0f);
>     Mat ret = new Mat();
>     Core.merge(splitColours, ret);
>     return ret;
> }
> ```